# How Avelut is healing, according to Rambam?

Tags: rambam, mourning-aveilus, psychology

The Rambam in Moreh Nevuchim (Chelek 3 Chapter 41) explains that mourning a deceased relative actually heals the great pain an Avel may have: " For mourners find comfort in crying and in excitement till, the body has not sufficient strength to bear the inner emotions; in the same manner as happy persons find rest in various kinds of play. Thus the Lord is merciful to her and gives her permission to continue her mourning and weeping till she is worn out."

Can anyone explain what the Rambam means- and how exactly does this work? 
Additionally does anyone know similar quotations from other Sefarim who link Avelut to the actual healing of an Avel?